# Get value in json string

Tags: php, json

I have this json result for which I would like to get the tempMaxC of a specific date (e.g. 2013-10-14).

I have tried this but it is not working.

```
$json=json_decode($json_reply);


printf("<p>Current temp</p>", 

    $json->{'data'}->{'weather'}['0']->{'date'}, 
    $json->{'data'}->{'weather'}['0']->{'tempMaxC'} );
```

Json:

```
    {
    "data": {
        "current_condition": [
            {
                "cloudcover": "25",
                "humidity": "81",
                "observation_time": "08:51 AM",
                "precipMM": "0.0",
                "pressure": "1019",
                "temp_C": "6",
                "temp_F": "43",
                "visibility": "10",
                "weatherCode": "113",
                "weatherDesc": [
                    {
                        "value": "Sunny"
                    }
                ],
                "weatherIconUrl": [
                    {
                        "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
                    }
                ],
                "winddir16Point": "SSW",
                "winddirDegree": "210",
                "windspeedKmph": "9",
                "windspeedMiles": "6"
            }
        ],
        "request": [
            {
                "query": "Adelboden, Switzerland",
                "type": "City"
            }
        ],
        "weather": [
            {
                "date": "2013-10-13",
                "precipMM": "3.2",
                "tempMaxC": "7",
                "tempMaxF": "44",
                "tempMinC": "0",
                "tempMinF": "32",
                "weatherCode": "116",
                "weatherDesc": [
                    {
                        "value": "Partly Cloudy"
                    }
                ],
                "weatherIconUrl": [
                    {
                        "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png"
                    }
                ],
                "winddir16Point": "SW",
                "winddirDegree": "233",
                "winddirection": "SW",
                "windspeedKmph": "12",
                "windspeedMiles": "7"
            },
            {
                "date": "2013-10-14",
                "precipMM": "0.6",
                "tempMaxC": "9",
                "tempMaxF": "48",
                "tempMinC": "0",
                "tempMinF": "32",
                "weatherCode": "116",
                "weatherDesc": [
                    {
                        "value": "Partly Cloudy"
                    }
                ],
                "weatherIconUrl": [
                    {
                        "value": "http://cdn.worldweatheronline.net/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png"
                    }
                ],
                "winddir16Point": "SSW",
                "winddirDegree": "213",
                "winddirection": "SSW",
                "windspeedKmph": "12",
                "windspeedMiles": "8"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zim84: which part isn't valid?

Comment: Try `printf("<p>Current temp %s %s</p>", 
    $json->{'data'}->{'weather'}['0']->{'date'}, 
    $json->{'data'}->{'weather'}['0']->{'tempMaxC'} );`

Comment: that is it. How do a loop it for every day?

Comment: @mark: with `foreach`. See my answer.

Comment: Have some difficulties get the weather desc value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell function [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) how arguments should be printed in format:

```
printf("<p>Date: %s | Temp: %s°C</p>", $arg1, $arg2);
```

Loop over days:

```
foreach ($json->data->weather as $day) {
    printf("<p>Date: %s | Temp: %s°C</p>", $day->date, $day->tempMaxC );
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/54302).

Comment: Clean and clear. +1. Here's a [working demo](https://eval.in/54301) if anyone's interested :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify the format in `printf` function. ie %d, %s ....

Try

```
printf("<p>Current temp %s %s</p>", $json->{'data'}->{'weather'}['0']->{'date'}, $json->{'data'}->{'weather'}['0']->{'tempMaxC'} );
```

Refer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php for printf syntax

Loop over days:

```
foreach( $json->{'data'}->{'weather'} as $days )
{
    printf("<p>Current temp %s %s</p>", 
    $days->{'date'}, 
    $days->{'tempMaxC'} );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$json=json_decode($json_reply);

    foreach($json->data->weather as $c ){


     if($c->date == '2013-10-14'){

       printf("<p>Date: %s | Temp: %s°C</p>", $c->date, $c->tempMaxC );

     }


    }
```

Comment: With the update, it'll only print the temperature for one day. I assume the OP is trying to print the temperature for all days in the JSON response. See Glavic's answer, below.

Comment: Now, your answer is just a duplicate. -1